# Adding the "New" facebook connect to an iphone app

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I implemented FaceBook connect a while back and it looks like there is a new api.

What are the changes in implementation or what are the differences?

Can the "old" one be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently developed an app a month ago and used old connect API in it which i've already integrated in my earlier apps, but it's not working on ipod touch with iOS4.1 (actually my client had this device).. It's working on every other device except this one.. So then I moved to newer Graph API and then it started working on the iPod Touch too.. So i recommend to go with the latest API... There's a nice tutorial available here:
 http://www.raywenderlich.com/1626/how-to-post-to-a-users-wall-upload-photos-and-add-a-like-button-from-your-iphone-app 
This tutorial will show you how to post pictures asynchronously on Facebook and other useful tutorials are available there too.

Answer (score 0):

The new one adds SSO (Single Sign-On) which stores facebook login credentials across the apps, so the user does not need to login on Facebook in each app.
I think that is the main change.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/

You can still use the old one.